# Only first parameter value is getting while calling controller method using Url.action.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, url.action

I am calling a controller method using `Url.action` like,

```
location.href = '@Url.Action("Display", "Customer", new { username = "abc",name = "abcdef",country = "India",email = "abc@hmail.com",phone = "9456974545"})';
```

My controller method is,

```
public void Display(string username, string name, string country, string email, string phone)
{    }
```

In this method, I can get only the value of first parameter (`username`). Its not getting other parameter values that is passed. All other values are null.

Please suggest me, whats wrong?

Comment: Can you see the querystring parameters in browsers address bar when ActionLink is clicked?

Comment: Yes. I can see the querystring parameters in browsers address bar.  The url is like this:          http://localhost:60710/Customer/Display?username=abc&amp;name=abcdef&amp;country=India&amp;email=abc%40hmail.com&amp;phone=9456974545

Comment: What is it ? Paste it here

Comment: http://localhost:60710/Customer/Display?username=abc&amp;name=abcdef&amp;country=India&amp;email=abc%40hmail.com&amp;phone=9456974545

Comment: Hmm.. Try like this `@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("Display","Customer", new { username = "abc",name = "abcdef"}))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default every content (which is not `IHtmlString`) emitted using a @ block is automatically `HTML encoded` by Razor.

So, `@Url.Action()` is also get encoded and you are getting plain text. And `&` is encoded as `&amp;`

If you dont want to Encode then you should use `@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("",""))`.

The answer for you question is :

```
location.href = '@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("Display", "Customer", new { username = "abc",name = "abcdef",country = "India",email = "abc@hmail.com",phone = "9456974545"}))';
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with '&' being encoded to the '& amp;'

model binder doesnt recognise this value. You need to prevent this encoding by rendering link with Html.Raw function.

Use '@Html.Raw(Url.Action......)'